# RPC Error when using jnpr.junos.utils.config Load command

Tags: python, eclipse

still rather new to Python. I've been referencing a few blogs regarding the jnpr.junos packages.  Specifically from Jeremy Schulman (http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Automation/Python-for-Non-Programmers-Part-2/bc-p/277682).  I'm simply trying to make sure I have the commands right.  I'm just attempting to pass simple commands to my SRX cluster.  I'm attempting to pass the following to an SRX650 cluster.

```
>>> from jnpr.junos.utils.config import Config
>>> from jnpr.junos import Device
>>> dev = Device(host='devip',user='myuser',password='mypwd')
>>> dev.open()
Device(devip)
>>> cu = Config(dev)
>>> cu
jnpr.junos.utils.Config(devip)
>>> set_cmd = 'set system login message "Hello Admin!"'
>>> cu.load(set_cmd,format='set')

Warning (from warnings module):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\junos_eznc-1.0.0-                py2.7.egg\jnpr\junos\utils\config.py", line 273
if any([e.find('[error-severity="error"]') for e in rerrs]):
FutureWarning: The behavior of this method will change in future versions.     Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
cu.load(set_cmd,format='set')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\junos_eznc-1.0.0-   py2.7.egg\jnpr\junos\utils\config.py", line 296, in load
return try_load(rpc_contents, rpc_xattrs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\junos_eznc-1.0.0-py2.7.egg\jnpr\junos\utils\config.py", line 274, in try_load
raise err
RpcError
```

I've done quite a bit of searching and can't seem to find anything as to why this RPC error is popping up.  I've confirmed that the syntax is correct and read through the jnpr.junos documentation for Junos EZ.

Answer (score 1):

Found that I was using an outdated version of junos.eznc.  Running `pip install -U junos-eznc` updated me to junos.eznc 1.3.1.  After doing this, my script worked properly.